# What is the meaning of the y-axis on graph that show's "difference"?

Tags: statistics, data-mining

I am reading the paper [From Amateurs to Connoisseurs:
Modeling the Evolution of User Expertise
through Online Reviews](http://i.stanford.edu/~julian/pdfs/www13.pdf) and I don't understand a graph. I don't understand what the y-axis is trying to show.

[image: graph]

Here is the relevant text (emphasis mine):

> Figure 1 examines the relationship between product ratings, user
>   experience level, and hoppiness, on RateBeer data.  Beers of three
>   types  are  considered  (in  increasing  order  of  hoppiness):
>   lagers, mild ales,  and  strong  ales.   The  x-axis  shows  the 
>   average  rating of products on the site (out of 5 stars), while **the
>   y-axis shows the difference between expert and novice ratings**. 
>   ‘Experts’ are those users to whom our model assigns the highest values
>   of our latent experience  score,  while  ‘novices’  are  assigned  the
>   lowest  value; Figure 1 then shows the difference in product bias
>   terms between the two groups.
>
> This simple plot highlights some of our main findings with regard to
>   user evolution: firstly, there is significant variation between the
>   ratings of beginner and expert users, with the two groups differing by
>   up to half a star in either direction.  Secondly, there exist entire
>   genres of products that are preferred almost entirely by experts or by
>   beginners: beginners give higher ratings to almost all lagers, while
>   experts give higher ratings to almost all strong ales; thus we might
>   conclude that strong ales are an ‘acquired taste’.

Questions:

1. If the y-axis show's "difference" how can it be negative?
2. How does the graph show a "significant variation between the ratings of beginner and expert users"? To me it looks like points are most densely clustered around y=0.
3. How does the graph show "there exist entire genres of products that are preferred almost entirely by experts or by beginners: beginners give higher ratings to almost all lagers, while experts give higher ratings to almost all strong ales"? We don't actually know who the experts or novices are (just their difference) so how can we say "beginners give higher ratings to lager" based on the graph?

I have a great deal of difficulty reading graphs in academic papers.

Answer (score 1):

I could be mistaken, but from what I gather:

1. It appears that how they're doing it is expert score *minus* novice score. So if an expert gives a 1 and novice gives a 4, then the "difference" is $1-4 = -3$.
2. The vertical spread signifies variations. As you go up, this signifies that the experts favored a particular item. As you go down, it shows that the novices preferred a particular item.
3. In combination with (2.), the color clustering shows the the experts favored strong ales and novices favored lagers. Thus the difference is positive and largest in the score. In the other direction, the graph shows that the difference was negative, meaning experts rated the lagers less favorably than the novice. So, even though on average the lagers received fewer stars, the novices did not give the lager as few stars as the experts. The novices gave more stars.

Comment: For 1 that would make sense if the graph had -3 and not -0.3. What is it the values are off by a scale factor of 10?

Comment: @Celeritas I just used those numbers as an example. What ended up happening was they probably standardized the scores or something. I'm not entirely sure. The main point is that I think they did expert score minus novice scores, so that negative values are possible.

Comment: Why would a published paper be so unclear? I'm not asking out of sarcasm, I've noticed a lot of papers like this. Isn't it to the author's benefit to be clear?

Comment: @Celeritas I don't claim that. I didn't read the paper. I'm sure you can find how they arrived at those values in the paper somewhere.

Comment: @Celeritas Also, by standardized, I meant out of 5, so I guess $2/5-4/5 = -3/5 = -.4$. I was thinking about GPAs at the time. In any case, there's usually a place where it has how they got the values. They probably thought they were being clear, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider the following example: Experts give 5 stars on beer A, novices give 4 stars. The difference is $5-4=1$. On the other hand, beer B gets 4 expert stars and 5 novice stars. Now the Difference is $4-5=-1$.
2. Most points lie above $y=0$ or below, indicating differences between expert and novice ratings.
3. Because we know the differences? Negative difference means novice preference, positive difference mens expert preference.

Comment: For 1 that would make sense if graph was -1 and not -0.1. What is it the values are off by a scale factor of 10?

Comment: The Differences are smaller than in my example. And they refer to the average star score. For example 4.5 expert stars vs 4.1 novice stars. Makes a difference of 0.4.

Comment: OK so there is an average star rating for an item for the novice group AND an average star rating for an item for the expert group? And the y-axis show's the difference between the two?